# Retrieve Total Elements from a Page Instance - Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Utilizing the Spring Framework's [`Page`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Page.html) interface I'm able to retrieve 50 users at a time with the code below:

```
int page = 0;
int pageSize = 50;
Page<User> userPage = userRepo.findByFirstName("Bob", page, pageSize);
List<User> userList = userPage.getContent();
```

This runs some query in the background to give me my first 50 users in my database. What I want to do is populate my `userList` ***without*** paging so that every is returned from the underlying query - is this possible?

I've tried the `hasNext()` method on my `Page` object but it runs in an endless loop

```
while(userPage.hasNext()){
    logger.info("Next page found");
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want paging you can ignore  spring Page and directly call `userRepo.findByFirstName("Bob");`

This will return all users in database whose firstName is bob

Your method signature should be

```
List<User> users = userRepo.findByFirstName("Bob");
```

Hope this solves your question

Comment: I know I can write a new repo method to retrieve this - I was just curious as to if it could be done utilizing the Page interface itself along with a `.next()`kind of scenario

Answer (score 1):

If you always want all users and not them by page, you need to adjust this on the Repository side. Change the signature of `findByFirstName` to return `List<User>` instead of `Page<User>`, and remove the Pageable parameter. Then, it will always return all. See more information on [how parameters are handled in the Spring Data documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.special-parameters).

If you need to sometimes paginate and sometimes get all data, then just add the `List<User>` version. The return type will depend on whether you pass a `Pageable` parameter or not based on Java's usual overloading.

The `hasNext()` method on Page merely tells you if a next page is available (for use in presenting navigation), it doesn't run another query. You would need to construct a new Pageable object and iterate through several calls to the `Page<User>` version in order to access all data through the Pageable interface, which is less efficient than just querying for what you actually want in the first place.

Comment: This more answers my question